# Adding one more condition in mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT ord_no,name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp, create_date, edited_date,status 
FROM orders o, customer c
where o.cust_id = c.id and status = 'CHECKED' order by 1;
```

I want to add this condition to the above query

```
edited_date < DATE_SUB(now(), interval 48 hour)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Should be considered as/??

Comment: do u mean edited_date shuold be equals "edited_date" ?

Comment: edited_date<DATE_SUB(now(),interval 48 hour)

Comment: Where is problem? Just add it.

Comment: Add into your query with a AND

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ord_no,name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp, create_date, edited_date, status 
FROM orders o, customer c
where o.cust_id = c.id 
and status = 'CHECKED' 
and edited_date < now() - interval 48 hour
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two tables, use the `JOIN` operator.

Why don't you add the `WHERE` clause that you need? It must be inserted before the `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT ord_no, name, mobile, address,  rate, mrp, create_date, edited_date, status 
FROM orders o
    INNER JOIN customer c
        ON o.cust_id = c.id
WHERE status = 'CHECKED' 
AND edited_date < DATE_SUB(now(),interval 48 hour)
ORDER BY 1
```